# Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm trying to run a Console Application (connect and read SQL), but getting error Incorrect syntax near '.'.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connstring = @"Data Source=Jama-Dharma\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cars;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);

        using (conn)
        {
            string query = "SELECT c.Name, c.Model c.Year FROM CarsCatalog c";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `c.Model c.Year` to `c.Model, c.Year`

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma here:

```
string query = "SELECT c.Name, c.Model, c.Year FROM CarsCatalog c";
```

(after c.Model)